# What's the meaning of 'i' in for loop?

Tags: variables, language-agnostic

In almost every programming language, they use variable **i** when they explain for loop. Like,

```
for i in 'string':
  print(i)
```

or

```
for(var i ; i<100 ; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

etc...

Does it mean anything? Or just a variable with no meaning?

I couldn't find any information about this in google search.

Comment: The variable `i`, as you have written it, is usually referred to as a "dummy" variable, because it only exists in the scope of the loop to keep track of the iteration number.  Try searching for what I have described.

Comment: `i` stands for index (Numerical data type)in almost every language.In advanced topic you will find advanced for loop

Comment: One of the things all developers do, besides calling test Projects "Hello World" :) You also can call it `j`

Comment: Um I know I can use i, x, j, t, m, n. etc. I just wondered why almost examples use 'i'. Anyway thank you for answer!

Comment: It might interest you (but be no surprise) to know that if you use two variables in the loop then the second one is usually named "j".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given two different example.

**For the first one**

`for i in 'string':
  print(i)`

For this one, the variable 'i' is the variable where the value will be put from your parameter (here 'string'). If i gave an array as parameter for instance, each value of array will be put in 'i', step by step (element [0], then element[1], etc...).
Note that this is a simplified view of this question and it doesn't work exactly like that for the program. But you can understand it as it.

**For the second one**

```
for(var i ; i<100 ; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

You declare explicitly a variable to be used. This declared will be used by the loop, incrementig by the step you had defined until it reaches limit you also defined.

It is slightly the same thing for both example. Hope i explain well

Answer (score 0):

it is just a common practice. Many people when learning see i being used as a variable name. But that's all it is. It is just a name that could be anything, you could us any other sequence of characters!

Comment: [i has it's origins in Fortran](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/why-do-most-of-us-use-i-as-a-loop-counter-variable).

Comment: @lloyd that page is interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

i is just a variable. Generally, it is referred to as "**iteration** for the loop".